# I am used to work(ing) inpendent(ly)

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Which form is correct and why?

- I am used to work independently.
- I am used to work independent.
- I am used to working independently.
- I am used to work independent.

Regards
Martin

Comment: The correct idiomatic form is the third one - but this type of question is best asked on English Language Learners.

Comment: 'Be used to [ ]' needs a noun or noun-like object, often an ing-form (never an infinitive). It must not be confused with say 'I used to work in the evenings'. // Ing-forms in the Quirk / Greenbaum analysis (there are others) are seen as being on a gradience between nounal and verbal end-points. This usage is sufficiently 'nouny' to follow 'I am used to' but at the same time sufficiently verby to accept an adverb modifier. (c) is the only correct choice here. // 'I am used to hard work', with a true noun object, shows that an adjective may be used in a related sentence.